# Find exact match word

Tags: ide, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I would like to search my project for "group".

However when I use the search dialog, I can see all "group" results, but also "groups", "grouping" and "grouper".

I don't want to see those last three, only the matches to "group".

Is there a way to do this in PyCharm 2017.1?

I have tried quotation marks and match-case box ticked. Neither did what I was after.

Comment: There is `words` option -- should match exact (as long as the text uses some common separation chars around such word).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Words](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/find-and-replace-in-path.html) option:

> Words
>
> Select this check box to have PyCharm search for whole words or their parts, (character strings separated with spaces, tabs,
> punctuation, or special characters).
>
> This check box is disabled, if the Regex check box is selected.

[image]